# Output dimensions of convolutional layer with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

The Keras tutorial gives the following code example (with comments):

```
# apply a convolution 1d of length 3 to a sequence with 10 timesteps,
# with 64 output filters
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(10, 32)))
# now model.output_shape == (None, 10, 64)
```

I am confused about the output size. Shouldn't it create 10 timesteps with a depth of 64 and a width of 32 (stride defaults to 1, no padding)? So `(10,32,64)` instead of `(None,10,64)`

Answer (score 2):

In k-Dimensional convolution you will have a filters which will somehow preserve a structure of first k-dimensions and will squash the information from all other dimension by convoluting them with a filter weights. So basically every filter in your network will have a dimension (3x32) and all information from the last dimension (this one with size 32) will be squashed to a one real number with the first dimension preserved. This is the reason why you have a shape like this.

You could imagine a similar situation in 2-D case when you have a colour image. Your input will have then 3-dimensional structure (picture_length, picture_width, colour). When you apply the 2-D convolution with respect to your first two dimensions - all information about colours will be squashed by your filter and will no be preserved in your output structure. The same as here.